# Why don't we have to use two '=' operands for mentioning equality for boolean variable?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

When I coding in a while loop in java , I discovered that we don't have to use two assignment operands for give meaning equality for JUST BOOLEAN VARİABLE(I found just it). What is the reason behind this situation? Thank you from now

` int a=30;
boolean d=true;

```
  while (a==30) {   <- We need to use like that for other variables
       
     
    }`
```

` int a=30;
boolean d=true;

```
  while (d=false) {   <- We need to use like that for other variables
       
     
    }`
```

Comment: Because that's the syntax of the language.  `=` is assignment, `==` is equality comparison.  Not every language uses this syntax, but a great many do.

Comment: Your second example isn't comparing `d` with `false`. It's *assigning* the value of `false` to `d`. That's *almost certainly* not what you intended.

Comment: In math, writing algorithms would often use an arrow like "<-" or "<=" for assignment, and "=" for equality. There was no single arrow character, and the "<" character was awkward to parse, so programming languages like Algol used ":=" for assignment, and "=" for equality. It worked, but ":=" was awkward to type, so C used "=" to assign and "==" to compare, which were a lot easier. That became the standard for most languages that followed, including Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **assignment** resolves to the assigned value. That sets `d` to `false` (and evaluates to `false`) and thus the `while` does not enter the loop body.

```
while (d=false) {
```

And you don't need any `=` for `boolean`(s).

```
while (!d) {
```

**or**

```
while (d) {
```

are correct, and don't involve assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really use two "=" operators (not operands), you would get a compiler error …

"=" is the operator for assignments, "==" is the equality operator, and "= =" is a syntax error.

How to use it is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76483631/1554195).